# Imac 2006 Snow leopard Disk Image Restore Problem

Tags: hard-drive, imac, restore, graphics

I have installed a new internal hard drive due to old one failing. I had made a complete Disk Image of the old Drive.
I re installed snow Leopard, and then tried to restore disk Image from External hard drive, it allowed me to pick the source of the restore "disk Image" but would not allow me to choose the Internal hard drive.
Can any one help with this problem
Thanks
Nicholas

Comment: what are you booted from? You can't change the volume from which you are booted, you need to boot from something else, DVD, USB, Recovery etc

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to restore onto the partition from which you booted (it sounds like installed Snow Leopard on the internal drive, then booted that and tried to overwrite it)?

Instead try booting from the Snow Leopard CD.  The install screen has a menu, from there you can choose the disk utility.  Run that and try to do the image restore from there.